# Google Sheets REGEXTRACT between two quotes

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, quotes, between

I'm trying to extract data between two quotes using the Google Sheets REGEXEXTRACT function.

The regex works perfect:

```
(?<=actor_email":")(.*?)(?=")
```

Data in the cell is:

```
{"account_name":"Test","actor_email":"test@test.com","user_email":"anyone@test.com"}
```

However, placing it within the Google Sheet gives an error.

Been trying a number of combinations with no luck.

Tried using: `(?<=actor_email""":""")(.*?)(?=""")`

The output should be: `test@test.com`

Comment: Use `actor_email":"([^"]+)"`

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "actor_email"":""([^""]+)""")
```

The pattern is `actor_email":"([^"]+)"`:

- `actor_email":"` - a literal substring
- `([^"]+)` - Capturing group 1 (the value extracted): any 1+ chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char (may be removed if this `"` can be missing)

Answer (score 0):

or eliminate quotes like:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, """", ), "actor_email:(.+),user_")
```

[image: 0]

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, """", " "), "actor_email : ([^ ]+)")
```

[image: 0]